# Автозагрузка программы WPF не работает

Tags: c#, wpf, реестр, автозагрузка

Не работает функция автозагрузки программы. Строка добавляется в регистр, но после включения системы не запускается. Отсутствие наличия кавычек никак не влияет на работу. Права администратора у приложения включены. Кроме этого, приложение отображается в диспечере задач во вкладке "Автозагрузка". Многое перепробовал, ничего не помогает. Не работает ни в Win 10, ни в Win 7. В директорию CurrentUser тоже не работает. Почему?

```
public void SetAutoload(bool set) {
   Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\", true);
   if (set) {
      key.SetValue("Appname", "\"" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Appname.exe" + "\"");
   } else {
      key.DeleteValue("Appname", false);
   }
   key.Close();
}
```

[image: Регистр]

UPD.: даже если добавить ярлык программы в папку автозапуска, то программа не запускается. Видимо это как-то связанно с правами администратора.

Comment: Добавить Ярлык в папку автозагрузки не?

Comment: @Сергей видимо так и придется поступить. Однако не понятно - некоторых программ нет как в регистре, так и в папке автозагрузки. Как они загружаются?

Comment: Отвечаю себе - из планировщика заданий (Task Scheduler). То есть существует 3 способа автозагрузки.

Comment: А если добавлять в `HKey_Current_User\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` ?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ уже добавил выше в описании вопроса, что если поместить в директорию HKey_Current_User, то так же не работает, к сожалению. Хотя там достаточно много записей автозапуска других программ и они нормально запускаются.

Comment: @Almost: Вангую, что программа таки запускается. Попробуйте в начале работы программы, до показа главного окна, вывести что-нибудь в файл для отладки.

Answer (score 4):

**UPD :** В Windows приложения, требующие повышения привилегий, можно нормально запустить только с помощью планировщика заданий. Повышение привилегий (которое в свою очередь приведёт к срабатыванию UAC, если он включён) невозможно для программ в автозагрузке (неважно в папке или через реестр).

Проблема была в том, что программа требовала права администратора, видимо у моей учетной записи их не было и соответственно программа не запускалась.

Права администратора были необходимы для того, чтобы была возможность добавлять\удалять записи в регистре, однако сейчас обнаружил, что изменив

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

на

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

регистр изменять можно.